# How do I see a log of which process was running on which CPU and for how long?

Tags: windows, process, core

Is there a program that logs this, or at least lets me see in real time which process is running on which core?  I don't think the task manager quite does either of these.

Comment: I don't think this has what you are looking for but it's a **lot** better than the standard task manager. Process Explorer found at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You want Process Explorer: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: Processor Explorer does not offer this feature. See [Determine which CPU a process is running on](http://superuser.com/questions/867127/determine-which-cpu-a-process-is-running-on?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are assuming that a process gets run on a fixed core, but this is not true. Processes will jump from core to core way to fast to monitor visually.

Comment: No, I am not assuming that.

Comment: @josh, in that case it is not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: It's clear what he asked for.  He asked for a log of process affinity and runtime.  Nothing in josh's question presumes affinity locking.

Answer (score 0):

For a command-line solution you may be interested in the pslist utility, which is part of the pstools suite. I'm afraid it doesn't show processor affinity, but it will enable you to log which processes are running and for how long.

The official site for pstools can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx).

You may also like to Google for the 'PsTools Primer' article by Wes Miller.