# Determine which CPU a process is running on

Tags: windows, cpu, process-explorer

Using Sysinternals' Process Explorer, is there a column that can be used to indicate which CPU a process is running on?  If no column, is there some other way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I see a log of which process was running on which CPU and for how long?](http://superuser.com/questions/103381/how-do-i-see-a-log-of-which-process-was-running-on-which-cpu-and-for-how-long)

Comment: @DavidPostill -- The best answer just points to Process Explorer's web page.  My question is: *given* process explorer, how to I determine which core a process is started on?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Requested in [2005](http://forum.sysinternals.com/feature-request-show-process-affinity_topic2625.html):

> I am very impressed with the features integrated in Process Explorer but would like to see an option to display each process CPU affinity in the main window as a column toggle.

No response.

Requested [in 2007](http://forum.sysinternals.com/view-affinity-column_topic12740.html):

> Thanks for superb utilities. My request is to add a column option to process explorer to display CPU affinity. That's it.

No response.

Similar discussed [in 2013](http://forum.sysinternals.com/multicore-monitoring_topic29280.html):

> It would be really nice if there were a new Process Performance View Column called Core Usage that would show a sum of the usage over the core that the process is running on.

Basic synopsis: It can't be done.

[Threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) are what are sent to cores for processing, not processes. Most modern processes have multiple threads.

If you manually set the [affinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity) for a process, then all threads for the process should stick to a single processor.  Since you manually set it, you should know which CPU it's on. ;)

But if you don't specify, then the thread(s) will be controlled by the OS and underlying processing hardware, and would jump around between processors at a speed that would be unwatchable, and very likely inaccurate by the time it was displayed to you.

Perhaps check out these SU question for more:

- [How does a process "pick" which core to run on?](https://superuser.com/questions/582965/how-does-a-process-pick-which-core-to-run-on)
- [What are threads, and what do they do in the processor?](https://superuser.com/questions/329904/what-are-threads-and-what-do-they-do-in-the-processor)

Also, from StackOverflow:

- [What is the difference between a process and a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread)

Now if you wrote the program, you could use the [GetCurrentProcessorNumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683181%28VS.85%29.aspx), which reports the current processor in use by the thread from which the function was called.

Using this will allow you to make *estimations* about processor usage by your threads, as you can never be sure where the threads will be one cycle to the next (again, unless you set the affinity on purpose).

More info:

- [Determine on which physical processor my code is currently running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341400/determine-on-which-physical-processor-my-code-is-currently-running)
- [Identify processor (core) is used by specific thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366932/identify-processor-core-is-used-by-specific-thread)

Comment: Nice answer ... :)

Comment: @DavidPostill -- Agreed.

Comment: Great answer, as it answers the specific question, gets into the history and whys, and helps to understand the concepts.

Comment: On both Linux and Windows it's possible to set the affinity on a per-thread basis. However, this is rarely ever useful, therefore rarely ever done, therefore displaying a per-thread affinity in a generic monitoring program *if it is set* is more-or-less useless - the vast majority would just let the kernel schedule as it pleases.

Comment: The OS could even switch your thread to another processor just after GetCurrentProcessorNumber is called (but before it starts executing) and again just after it returns, so the result would be neither the processor at the time of the call, nor the processor at the time the call returns!

Answer (score 10):

This can be done by capturing a xperf trace and opening it with [Windows Performance Analyzer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448170.aspx) (WPA.exe) from the Windows Performance Toolkit, here you can add a column CPU to see which CPU (Core) the process is running:

[image]

Comment: Nice.  Does it list the same process under each CPU (if it's using more than one)?  Since it's using a captured xperf trace, does that mean it's not live reporting?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 ETW events can be also consumed at runtime. Writing them into a ETL file is just one way. Yes, it lists processes under both CPU when it uses both.